# Xposed - how to hook Date Class android

Tags: android, xposed

As you can see below to get date when we use this code

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.print("Due date:", date);
```

now how can i change the date before displaying result ,as it is not using any method so how to hook something like above ?

is there any way we can hook this to change result with xpose hook module ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, but you can set the specific date by `Date date = new Date(12345);` where 12345 is time since 1/1/1970 in milis.

Comment: hello i am talking about xpose hook,not setting up time

Comment: Date class has setMinute, setHour, setMinutes methods. You should hook these method so you can change the Time part of the date. Date also has a setTime(long) method which you can hook. If you need to hook the 'new Date()' you can just hook the constructor in which you can call setter methods

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption *"it is not using any method"* is simply wrong.
Your sample code uses two "methods" that can be hooked by Xposed:

The first "method" is the `Date()` constructor. You can hook it using `XposedHelpers.findAndHookConstructor(..)`. In the `afterHookedMethod(..)` you could then modify the date object.

The second method is `Date.toString()`. It is a regular constructor and can be hooked like any other method.

Comment: well thank you i needed was finandhookconstructor  ,i do not know why someone rated it -1,but the application i am trying to hook simple uses date = new date(); and use simpledateformat later well i know i can hook methods like parse in simpledateformat or date.tostring (tostring can be hooked) but what i was looking was that constructor